# If $R_3$ is a finitely generated $R_2$-module and $R_2$ is a finitely generated free $R_1$-module, can we say that $R_3$ is a free $R_1$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noetherian

Let $R_1 \subseteq R_2 \subseteq R_3$ be Noetherian rings. If $R_3$ is a finitely generated $R_2$-module and $R_2$ is a finitely generated free $R_1$-module, then $R_3$ is a finitely generated $R_1$-module. I was wondering if we can say that $R_3$ is a free $R_1$-module? if not (as I think so), is there any condition we can add to the statement to make it true?

Comment: The condition can be that $R_2$ is a free $R_1$ module and $R_3$ is a free $R_2$ module

Comment: If $R_2$ is a free $R_1$ module and $R_3$ is a free $R_2$ module, then you have your result..

Comment: Thank you. I know that but I was wondering if there is another condition as I cannot prove that $R_3$ is free over $R_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question **"can [we] say that $R_3$ is a free $R_1$-module?"**
is No. Let $R_1=\mathbb Z$, $R_2 = \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2)$,
$R_3 = \mathbb Z[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2,2y)$.

As for the question **"is there any condition we can add
to the statement to make it true?"**
the answer is basically "Nothing nonobvious will work", as one sees by considering what happens in the case where $R_1=R_2$.

Comment: The last case $R_1=R_2$ is enough! Thank you.